# How to block torrent downloads by squid?

Tags: linux, squid, rhel5, bittorrent, block

I am using linux (RHEL 5) server with few windows xp client machines ,

I would like to block torrent downloads at clients,

I am using squid 2.6 stable.

- How can i do this by squid ?
- Is there any other options for to do
  this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a blacklist for different files. All you have to do is blacklist .torrent files.

But in reality you should have a decent firewall capable of blocking Bit Torrent ports... Any firewall will do this with a bit of configuration and tweaking.

If you really don't want a firewall, you could always use an IDS such as Snort to watch the traffic and notify you of any BT traffic.

Comment: This will block the download of torrent files, but not the download of torrent content (unless clients reach the internet only through squid, in which case bittorrent won't work at all).

Comment: edited to mention such case

Answer (score 1):

1. Block downloading of ".torrent" files and "application/x-bittorrent" content type.
2. Limit maximum concurrent connections. Bittorrent will connect hundreds of connections for better speed, so limit the maximum connections number can limit its downloading speed.

Answer (score 0):

squid is a caching proxy. But you can as Antoine suggested to block .torrent files. But this is quite useless.

What you need is a good firewall and only open up for business critical services.

Comment: Actually, Squid is a proxy server, that can do blacklisting, and caching, and reverse proxying too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block the torrent from being downloaded, then the following step should be performed:

1. Open terminal on the desktop of the RHEL5 Enterprise Server
2. Run `vi /etc/squid/squid.conf`
3. After the file opens, search for `#http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports`
4. Remove the `#` in front of the line then the torrent became block, if you assign the "#" sign in front of the line then its started to download from the torrent.

Comment: Rajkumar for your kind information in squid 2.6 **# Deny CONNECT to other than SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports**

is bydefault uncommented but still user can download torrent.